# Ajax request takes too long to complete when working with large database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, yii

I am working on a website written in **Yii framework** (version 1.1.14) that allows uploading and displaying news. The admin of the site can select three news to promote to homepage and specify the order in which they are displayed. I am using **Mysql** database. The **news** table has two fields: **isChecked** (0 or 1) and **homepagePos** (integer) in addition to the other fields. The **isChecked** field determines whether the news is selected for displaying in homepage and the **homepagePos** field determines the order in which the news are displayed. I have used jquery's sortable plugin to sort the news. When the user selects which news to display and clicks save button, the news ids are sent to php via ajax.

The javascript portion to send the values to news controller is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveToHomepage', function() 
{
    var url = ajaxRequestSendUrl;   //ajaxRequestSendUrl contains url to news controller's promote to homepage method.
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {
            contentIds: contentIds, //contentIds contains an array of news Ids in certain order
            },
        success: function() {
        // Show success message
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Some error occured. Please reload the page and try again.');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the promote to homepage method in news controller:

```
public function actionHomepage()
{
    $allNews = News::model()->findAll();
    $value = $_GET['contentIds'];
    foreach ($allNews as $news) {
        if($news->id == $value[0] ||$news->id == $value[1] ||$news->id == $value[2])
        {
            $news->isChecked = 1;
            $news->homepagePos = array_search($news->id, $value); //Assign index of the array as the position
            $news->save();
        }
        else
        {
            $news->isChecked = 0;
            $news->homepagePos = -1;
            $news->save();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the news table I have has over 2k data. So the ajax call takes really long time (over a minute) to complete. Is there any way I can optimize the code or is there other way I can approach this to reduce the time taken to complete this operation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: had you tried to use pagination?

Comment: @jimmypage why don't you query the model with the id you have instead of fetching the entire `News` model ?

Comment: Why do you save in a fetch?

Comment: It is taking so long because you have to get the whole table, make changes in the model and then update each row through the model. Why don't you instead do it with two queries: One first to set the whole table to not checked status, and the second one to set the checked status only in the rows with the selected id?

Comment: Dont fetch all news as this might take a lot of time depending how many news entries there are. Instead you could reset the `isChecked` and `homepagePos` fields beforehand and then query the table with the IDs you got and then set the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three queries: One first to set the whole table to not checked status, and the rest to set the checked status only in the row each selected id

```
public function actionHomepage()
{
    $values = $_GET['contentIds'];
    $sql = "UPDATE news SET idChecked=0,homepagePos = -1";
    Yii::app()->db
        ->createCommand($sql)
        ->execute();
    for($ii = 0; $ii < 3; $ii++) {
        $sql = "UPDATE news SET idChecked = 1,homepagePos = ':homepagePos' WHERE id=:id";
        Yii::app()->db
            ->createCommand($sql)
            ->bindValues(array(':homepagePos' => array_search($ii, $values), ':id' => $values[$ii]))
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have made small changes in this and now it works... just as expected and faster!!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, but why don't you get the filtered records from the database itself by sending the id's of selected news. I don't know your backend language. Seems, you are getting all the records and applying filtering. which consumes time. Instead get the filtered news from the database.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its taking a long time because you're fetching all the records and then updating those three `id`. You could try this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition( "id" , $value ) ; // $value = array ( 1, 2, 3 );
News::model()->updateAll(array('isChecked'=>'1','homepagePos'=>'val2'), $criteria);
```

You could do an update before hand to reset all the `homepagePos` and then update only the ids you need.